# Secure upload img/swf in php

Tags: php, image, security, upload, flash

I have flash games website. In my panel I already made the "upload game" page, that you can insert the data about the game. Now, I have to `upload image, and swf file`, how should I do that secure?

Please tell me about the checks that I should do (for image and for swf).

And if there is any anti virus that working with php, please tell me about it.

Thanks people.

Comment: Picture upload is fine, but swf (flash) upload should be reviewed after uploading by administrator. Google for php secure file upload, I am sure you will find tons of tutorials how to do it. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png","swf");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/x-shockwave-flash")
        )

        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the file extension and then use **PHP FILE INFO** extension to verify the file type DO NOT Rely on extension checks.